# Как написать функцию подсчета факториала без циклов в JS?

Tags: javascript

Как написать функцию подсчета факториала без циклов в JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать тернарный оператор:

```
function factorial(n) {
        return (n != 1) ? n * factorial(n - 1) : 1; 
}
console.log(factorial(5));
```